# How do I fix brew doctor errors?

Tags: homebrew

I'm very much a newbie when it comes to all this so forgive my incompetence.

When I run brew Doctor, I get the following. Can someone help?

```bsh
[/usr/local]$ brew doctor

Error: Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH can break dynamic linking.
You should probably unset it.
Error: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with
brew link f will cause other formulae to detect them during the
./configure step. This may cause problems when compiling those
other formulae.

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to brew unlink these brews:

libxml2

Error: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
/usr/local/lib/libcharset.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/liblcms.1.0.19.dylib /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.4.dylib /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand.4.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtiffxx.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libwmf-0.2.7.1.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libwmflite-0.2.7.0.1.dylib
Error: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
/usr/local/lib/libcharset.la /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.la /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.la /usr/local/lib/liblcms.la /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.la /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand.la /usr/local/lib/libpng15.la /usr/local/lib/libtiff.la /usr/local/lib/libtiffxx.la /usr/local/lib/libwmf.la /usr/local/lib/libwmflite.la
Error: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/lcms.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng15.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickWand.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/Wand.pc
Error: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
/usr/local/lib/libcharset.a /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.a /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a /usr/local/lib/liblcms.a /usr/local/lib/libpng15.a /usr/local/lib/libtiff.a /usr/local/lib/libtiffxx.a /usr/local/lib/libwmf.a /usr/local/lib/libwmflite.a
Error: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew's core.
Unless you know what you are doing, you should run:
cd /usr/local && git reset --hard
Error: Some directories in your path end in a slash.
Directories in your path should not end in a slash. This can break other
doctor checks. The following directories should be edited:
/usr/local/git/bin/
[/usr/local]$
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
Error: Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH can break dynamic linking. You should probably unset it. Error: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar. Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with brew link f will cause other formulae to detect them during the ./configure step. This may cause problems when compiling those other formulae.

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries with other strange results.
```

This is asking you to unset your Dynamic Loading Library Path. You can do this by finding out where you set it and removing it. Most likely, you have a line in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile that looks like `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
You may wish to brew unlink these brews:

libxml2
```

When Brew links, it's creating a symlink to the installation. It's how you can have python2.6. python2.7 installed but `python` will run one of them.

`brew unlink libxml2`

```
Error: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs: /usr/local/lib/libcharset.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/liblcms.1.0.19.dylib /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.4.dylib /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand.4.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtiffxx.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libwmf-0.2.7.1.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libwmflite-0.2.7.0.1.dylib Error: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files: /usr/local/lib/libcharset.la /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.la /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.la /usr/local/lib/liblcms.la /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.la /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand.la /usr/local/lib/libpng15.la /usr/local/lib/libtiff.la /usr/local/lib/libtiffxx.la /usr/local/lib/libwmf.la /usr/local/lib/libwmflite.la Error: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/lcms.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng15.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickWand.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/Wand.pc Error: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries: /usr/local/lib/libcharset.a /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.a /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a /usr/local/lib/liblcms.a /usr/local/lib/libpng15.a /usr/local/lib/libtiff.a /usr/local/lib/libtiffxx.a /usr/local/lib/libwmf.a /usr/local/lib/libwmflite.a
```

These are residual files from other installations. You can delete them.

`rm FILENAME`

```
Error: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew's core. Unless you know what you are doing, you should run: cd /usr/local && git reset --hard
```

Here, it is telling you that you made modifications to Homebrew files. Luckily, Homebrew is stored in Git version control so you can revert those changes.

`cd /usr/local && git reset --hard`

```
Error: Some directories in your path end in a slash. Directories in your path should not end in a slash. This can break other doctor checks. The following directories should be edited: /usr/local/git/bin/
```

The PATH variable is where your computer searches for programs when you type it in the command line. You can see your path with `echo $PATH`.

Standards dictate that all the paths in PATH should not end in a slash. Thus, homebrew is asking you to fix it.

`nano ~/.bashrc` or `nano ~/.bash_profile` and look for '/usr/local/git/bin/' and remove the trailing slash.

Comment: Also remember to restart terminal or run source ~/.bashrc when you edit that file

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to brew as well.  When I first tried, I ended up with a laundry list of errors.  Not all *needed* to be fixed for me to use brew as I needed it.  In particular, I was able to ignore the

```
Unbrewed * were found in /usr/local/lib
```

messages that I was getting.  I believe those are only a problem when your use of brew installed packages will interfere with ones you've installed before (in my case, it was NTFS-3g, not related to my future uses of brew).