# Graphviz and Brew doctor - Unexpected dylibs error

Tags: graphviz, homebrew

Just did a `brew install graphviz` on Mountain Lion which gave me this error

> Error: Failed executing: make install (graphviz.rb:47)

Thought I'd just uninstall it, so ran `brew uninstall graphviz` but got

> Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz

Then thought I'd try `brew doctor`, but it gives me this error:

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libcdt.5.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libcgraph.6.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libgvc.6.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libgvpr.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libpathplan.4.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libxdot.4.dylib
Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcdt.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcgraph.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgvc.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgvpr.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpathplan.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libxdot.pc
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running these:

```
brew install libtool
```

Then try reinstalling graphviz.

And then check this out:
[xlib-h-not-found-when-building-graphviz-on-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465258/xlib-h-not-found-when-building-graphviz-on-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion)

Comment: Thanks very much. I did this and get a /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.28.0: 4.0K - but running 'brew doctor' still gives me the dylibs error described. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I find these very unhelpful errors, but it seems that brew got lost after the upgrade to Mountain Lion, maybe this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580813/how-do-i-fix-brew-doctor-errors

Comment: Thank you. I removed the files like he says to do in the answer you linked to and now my system is raring to brew :-)