# Can't run brew doctor, it gives out warnings

Tags: terminal, installation, homebrew

I was trying to run brew doctor on the terminal but when i do, it tell me some warnings... i paste it:

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libjansson.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libjansson.la

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libjansson.a
    /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    jansson
    libidn
    libtool
    libusb
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it sounds as if you have may have installed libjansson and libusb tool yourself, without using brew.

Aside from that, follow it's instructions, and run the following commands...

```
brew link jansson
brew link libidn
brew link libtool
brew link libusb
```

It may ask you to added the `--overwrite` flag, which you can first check what action is will take by adding the `--dry-run` flag too.

Comment: Thanks, but when i run the commands says me that /usr/local/Cellar/libtool(or jansson etc..)/2.4.2
/usr/local/opt is not writable. You should change its permissions.

How can i change the permissions? PS i just run brew install

Comment: `sudo chmod go+rw /usr/local/opt` I would also suggest reading the man page and homebrew's wiki when you have time.

Comment: Thanks man! it finally works! certainly i'll read the wiki ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer, it tells that residual files from old installations can be deleted. [How do I fix Brew errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580813/how-do-i-fix-brew-doctor-errors/11028753#11028753)